# El comando "Flutter: New Project" ha dado lugar a un error: command 'flutter.createProject' not found

Tags: flutter, vscode

Me sale este error al momento de querer crear un nuevo proyecto de flutter:

> El comando "Flutter: New Project" ha dado lugar a un error
> command 'flutter.createProject' not found

Comment: Disculpas...!!!  el error es el siguiente ..... El comando "Flutter: New Project" a dado lugar a un error..... comman "Flutter: New Project" not found

Comment: ok lo actualice

Comment: Si tengo todas las extenciones y ya reinstale vscode

Comment: si reinstale las extenciones tambien!!! en la variable de entorno tengo esta ruta C:\src\flutter\bin pero la de dart no sera que me falta esa??

Comment: Probalo, a ver qué tal :)

Comment: consulta como subo una imagen aqui en los comentarios

Comment: No se puede :) Si querés agregar detalles adicionales a tu pregunta, debés editarla. No olvides que el código y los mensajes de error deben ir siempre _como texto, con formato_. Sé siempre descriptivo cuando comentás tu problema. No olvides además darle el formato correspondiente al texto.

Comment: ok ya lo resolvi  en la extencion de dart en vs code le cambie a version preliminar y ahi levanto sin problema porque podria ser eso=?

Comment: Realmente no tengo idea. Si ya resolviste tu problema, no olvides colocar como respuesta (en base a [answer]) los pasos que seguiste para llegar a ese punto, y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.